# Cannot read Material UI classes

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Im runnign a React app using Material UI just to try some stuff.Im trying to customize the components in the way that its explained on the original documentation but applying some changes beacause in my case im using classes insthead of hooks, but i dont know why it keeps showing the error : Cannot read property 'root' of undefined. So thats basically it, it doesent appear to be any "classes" on my props, but i dont know why.
Any idea? (Sorry for my english btw)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
...
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import "./Product.css";

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
});

export class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isExpanded: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { isExpanded } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    debugger;
    return (
      <Container maxWidth="lg" className="full-container">
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <Accordion
          expanded={isExpanded}
          onChange={() => this.setState({ isExpanded: !isExpanded })}
        >
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
            id="panel1bh-header"
          >
            <Typography className="heading">General settings</Typography>
            <Typography className="secondaryHeading">
              I am an accordion
            </Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>
              Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sollicitudin nulla et quam mattis
              feugiat. Aliquam eget maximus est, id dignissim quam.
            </Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(Product);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add all of your imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with this component code.
From this file you're exporting two things, one is named export `App` class and the other is default export with `withStyles` hoc. and to use `useStyles`, you need to import the default export of this file. you probably importing the component like `import {App} from './App'` and that's why you're getting the error. Import the default export like this, `import App from './App'`

Comment: It woked!!Sorry for the late response, but i was too busy on another project. Really really really thanks a lot! <3

Answer (score 0):

I've got you working code at the following.

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

I think you have an invalid import. Can you please update your question to include what imports you are using.

I changed the icon in the accordion and used the following imports

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Accordion,
  AccordionSummary,
  Typography,
  AccordionDetails,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { ExpandMoreOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";
```

The working document.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Accordion,
  AccordionSummary,
  Typography,
  AccordionDetails,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { ExpandMoreOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
});

export class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isExpanded: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { isExpanded } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    debugger;
    return (
      <Container maxWidth="lg" className="full-container">
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <Accordion
          expanded={isExpanded}
          onChange={() => this.setState({ isExpanded: !isExpanded })}
        >
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreOutlined />}
            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
            id="panel1bh-header"
          >
            <Typography className="heading">General settings</Typography>
            <Typography className="secondaryHeading">
              I am an accordion
            </Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>
              Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sollicitudin nulla et quam mattis
              feugiat. Aliquam eget maximus est, id dignissim quam.
            </Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Product);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can make a working sandbox from your code https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-satoshi-lx7of?file=/demo.js:27-499. I think the problem comes from where you import other MUI components, since this is the only place that I modified (because you didn't provide your full imports).